# upper to lower case in 68K

Tags: assembly

I want to convert from upper to lower case.
this the code I wrote but still not get where is the error. I know to covert from upper to lower I have subtract 32 so that what trying to do it. But, after I run the program it does not show the result in lower case.
Thanks for any help.

```
START       ORG    $1000
            MOVE.L USERID,D0
            SUBI.L   #32323232,D0          
            MOVE.L  D0,result            
            SIMHALT 
USERID      DC.L    'ABCD1234'           
result      DS.L    1
            END     START
```

Comment: You would be far better off using bit-masking.  Subtracting 32 can have unexpected behaviors when you have something other than an upper case character... like a lower case character.

Comment: That's 32 decimal, not hex - repeating that decimal number 4 times is going to subtract essentially a random number. Use hex. P.S. to go from upper case to lower, you need to add not subtract.

Comment: @David Hoelzer: Thanks, what do you mean by  bit-masking, sorry I am new programmer in 68K

Comment: @ Mark Ransom: thanks, I tried by add #20, but not repeating. However, still I did not get it.

Comment: The accepted answer addresses bit masking for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#32323232` is ... well, that, value `32323232`. But you tried to apply it to 4 BYTE characters loaded as 32 bit (LONG) value, which means each character occupies it's own 8 bits, like after `MOVE.L USERID,D0` the `D0` is `$41424344`, where `$41 == 65 == 'A', $42 == 66 == 'B', $43 == 67 == 'C', $44 == 68 == 'D'`.

In hexadecimal formatting each letter (8 bits) has exactly two hexadecimal digits, because 1 hexadecimal digit is value from `0` to `15` and that's exactly what 4 bits can encode in total, so it's perfect conversion 4 bits <=> 1 hexadecimal digit.

But if you will take that value `$41424344` and convert it from hexadecimal to decimal, you will get `1094861636`. It's still the same value, but suddenly the letters are not easily "visible" in it any more. They are hidden there as `65*256*256*256 + 66*256*256 + 67*256 + 68 = 1094861636`, as 8 bits can encode `256` different values, so by multiplying by power of `256` you can place decimal value in particular BYTE of LONG. So for example `66*256*256` means "third least significant byte in long", or technically it means to move decimal value `66` "to left by 16 bits". And indeed, if you would load `66` into `D1` and do `LSL.L #16,D1`, you would calculate `66*256*256 == 66*65536 == (66<<16)` without using multiply instruction.

It's all about how numbers "base N formatting" works, that you have M digits of (0 to N-1) value, each digit representing multiply of i-th power of N depending on it's position in the number. Ie. value `123` in decimal (base 10) formatting is written as "123", where the "1" represents value amount of 10<sup>2</sup>, "2" stands for 10<sup>1</sup>, and "3" is for 10<sup>0</sup> values.

Mind you, the written "123" form is not number `123`. Number `123` is purely abstract entity, the decimal formatting used to write it down here like "123" is actually imperfect mirror of the value itself, with few limitations imposed by the decimal formatting upon this format, not upon the real value. Probably the simplest example of these imperfections of "base N" formats: the value `123` has in decimal second valid form: `122.99999..` with infinite amount of "9" fractions. It's still the same value `123` exactly, but written differently (and not as practically, as the finitely short "123" variant).

So back to your `32323232` ... you did want to place each `32` at particular BYTE in LONG, but that would require you to use `32*256*256*256 + 32*256*256 + 32*256 + 32 = 538976288` decimal value. Which is PITA to calculate in head.

If you ever wondered *"why Assembly sources are full of those annoying hexadecimal numbers?"*, here comes the point of this lengthy answer and all of those numerical exercises.

`32` is `$20` (you should be able to convert powers of two in your head on the fly). And if you want to place `$20` at particular byte positions, you have to write `#$20202020` (it's still the same `538976288` of course). That's certainly manageable without calculator, while writing the source, right? So that's the answer, why the hexadecimal formatting is so popular among Assembly programmers, it allows you to see immediately, what are values of particular bytes in word/long value.

Just for curiosity, your `32323232` value splits into bytes as `$01ED36A0` (can you see them now? Each byte is 8 bits = two 4 bits, and 4 bits = single hexadecimal digit).

---

And as Mark noted, you need to add. So fix of your source:

```
        MOVE.L   USERID,D0
        ADDI.L   #$20202020,D0
        MOVE.L   D0,result
```

This will indeed show "abcd" in memory at address `result` (`$101E`).

---

About ["bit manipulation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation): if you will take a look at ASCII table with hexadecimal formatting, you will see that the upper/lowercase letter have the same value except the 6th bit, which is clear for uppercase letter, and set for lowercase.

So by doing `ORI.L #$20202020,D0` you will set 6th bits in each byte packed in `D0` long, effectively doing "to lower case" for letter ASCII values.

`ANDI.L #~$20202020,D0` (`~$20202020` is `$DFDFDFDF`, inverted `$20` bit pattern) will do "to upper case" for ASCII letters.

`XORI.L #$20202020,D0` will flip upper to lower and lower to upper case, for ASCII letters.

All of these will meaninglessly mangle other ASCII characters, like digits and symbols, so these bit tricks are usable only when you know your value contains letters only (*"garbage in, garbage out"*).

Comment: Thank you very much it works, and I understand much better from what you explaned